# Programmatically setting my constraints between two SKSpriteKitNodes' widths?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am having a problem programmatically setting my constraints for the leading and trailing edges of my two SKSpriteKitNodes.

```
    //Set the constraints
    let highScoreHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: highScoreStringNode,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: highScoreLabelNode,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 10)
    self.view!.addConstraint(highScoreHorizontalConstraint)
```

I get the following console error message and a SIGABRT:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView or subclass'
```

What is causing the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is in the error message, you are trying to constraint an SKSpriteNode which inherits from SKNode and has nothing to do with UIView - which the constraints apply to.

try using SKPhysicsJoint